# Internet Explorer unable to open SharePoint Issue, SCRIPT5: Access is denied

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, explorer

Internet Explorer unable to open SharePoint Issue, SCRIPT5: Access is denied

I am able to open all the office apps in IE. 
However, when ever i m trying to open Sharepoint content. 
it is stuck at login.microsoftonline.net/..... "working"

then in the IE Developer tools. it says "SCRIPT5: Access is denied"

However, with Chrome/Edge. none of these issues occur. or with Other Accounts/User in that machine.

except in that Account/User.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following method:

Log out of all Microsoft accounts in IE and [clear browser cache and cookies in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lqn0.png):
Open Tools -> Internet Options -> Delete -> Check **Temporary Internet files and website files**, **Cookies and website data** -> Click Delete.

Then [set prompt for user authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfPmq.png): Security -> Select the zone in which your site lies -> Custom Level -> Scroll down in **user authentication** -> Select **Prompt for Username and Password**. > Click OK, Apply. Now you can close the browser and restart and try accessing the site again.

There also might be IE used the account that logged into the server to access the website, you could refer to this [similar thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55ec4a36-8b7a-4333-b8c6-11b30ac645fe/sharepoint-2013-cannot-access-through-ie?forum=sharepointgeneral&forum=sharepointgeneral).

Besides, you could refer to [the resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/access-denied-or-need-permission-error-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business#when-accessing-a-sharepoint-site) of access denied when accessing a SharePoint site for more information.